# not complete solution in computation of singular cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology

I know how to compute singular cohomology of single point. Then I want to compute cohomology of $\mathbb{Z}$. Consider $C_{k}(\mathbb{Z})=\oplus_{i\in Z} C_{k}(point)$. $$\text{Hom}(A\oplus B, G)= \text{Hom}(A,G)\oplus \text{Hom}(B,G).$$ Then $$H^{k}(A\oplus B)=H^{k}(A)\oplus H^{k}(B).$$
And finally we have $H^{0}(Z)=\oplus_{i\in Z}\mathbb{Z}$.
My answer is in what I'm wrong? Why is it not complete solution?

Comment: What is meant by 'point'?

Answer (score 1):

You should have that $$\operatorname{Hom}(\oplus A_i,B)\cong \prod\operatorname{Hom}(A_i,B).$$

Comment: Why the product? If it is obvious let's send me to the textbook..

Comment: @boris1993 The proof is contained in the Wikipedia page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules